# Is it a bad idea to create css classes for text tags?

Tags: html, css

Just wondering, is it a bad idea to say create css classes for text tags.

Lets say the h1 tag is 24px font-size, but I want bigger font size of 36px for some reason and create a css class for the h1 tag like below.

```
<h1 class="special-title">
or
<h1 id="special-title">
```

Is there a rule of thumb for this ? As in when it's considered appropriate ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: `HTML` is all about semantic. `CSS` is all about styling.

This means:

- `<h1>` is a very important headline
- `<h2>` is a less important headline
- `<h6>` is a very very less important headline

If I understand you right, you want to style your headline `<h1>` on different ways. Please think about, why you want to style it on different ways. Are they on the same level of importance?

If not, you can give the less important headline the `<h2>` tag, and the important one the `<h1>` tag.

CSS:

```
h1 { font-size:36px; }
h2 { font-size:24px; }
```

If they have the same level of importance, your approche of `special-headline` is the right way to handle this. You should do this as a `Class`. `Id` means it is a unique object. But I assume, you have more then one `special-headline`.

Comment: Although you probably want the size to be "larger" or "+1" or "3ex", so that it scales properly if the tag scales.

Comment: Hey Christian, yes you are right i want to style h1 on different ways. Lets just say I have a blog on the index page has not full blog posts, but more post teasers. The h1 i will use will sit on a background image, so I want the h1 text to be very readable, i will give it a class and size it to 64px. Now when you will view the single post page, it will go back to normal h1 size. Is this good practice ?

Comment: @Dan, I personaly would say this should be different css. If you want combine them for example, if youre on your Landing page, you could have `<body class="landingpage">` and on the detail page `<body class="detailpage"`>` On Css side you have `.landingpage h1 { font-size:64px; }` and `.detailpage h1 { font-size:36px; }`

Answer (score 2):

The ID value should be unique and used only one time for one element on the page. The class can be reused for many H1 as in your example.

Your CSS would then be

```
#special-title {
    /* style for this one element only */
}
.special-title {
    /* style for all elements using this class*/
}
```

A good rule of thumb is use IDs for unique single elements and classes for repeating styles for many elements.

Putting it in practice, you could do something like this:

```
<style>
    #special-title { /* a unique ID selector for one element */
        color: red;
        font-size: 3em;
    .special-title { /* a class selector for many elements */
        color: blue;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
</style>
<h1 id="special-title">one unique style</h1>
<h1 class="special-title">more uniform styles</h1>
<h1 class="special-title">more uniform styles</h1>
<h1 class="special-title">more uniform styles</h1>
```

The first header is different than the rest because we wrote a CSS rule for its unique ID.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying heading for some reason can be done by using class or Id.
for me, it is okay as long as you use classes for the same uses and Id selector for unique ID (once uses).

Answer (score 1):

There is no general rule of thumb to say you should use an `id` or a `class` to do that. However, I always tend to go with class. Here's why!

- Classes are lighter than ids. an id adds much more weight than a class does.
- Id's are prone to collision since they should be unique and if you duplicate them, you may end up with unwanted results.
- For the reason above, classes are re-usable and ids are not.

For more reasons, you should give this a definite read.

http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/